# How can I prevent seeds from being run on the production environment with knex.js?

Tags: javascript, database, knex.js

I'm using [Knex.js](https://knexjs.org) to manage migrations and seeds in my project, with connection options managed by the `--env` switch to individual commands.

How can I ensure that the seed commands like `knex seed:run` are never run against the production environment?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by giving it a seeds directory that doesn't exists. If it is then run in production it will crash with a `no such file or directory`.

As an example here is my `knexfile.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  ...,
  production: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: ...,
    seeds: {
      directory: 'you-are-not-able-to-run-seeds-in-production'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it:

1. In development, make sure to create an env variable like "APP_ENV=development"
2. In every seed file, I put:

```js
if (process.env.APP_ENV !== "development") {
  console.error("Error: seeds can only be used in development");
  process.exit(1);
}
```

Done!

Answer (score 1):

For example by not using seeds or by adding code to start of every seed, which checks that if knex client configuration is not pointing to dev database, it will throw an error.

There is nothing builtin functionality in knex to prevent that.

Comment: Yep, the checking on the environment is what I was expecting. Do you know a good way to interrogate knex on which env it is using?

Comment: Maybe you can figure it out from `knex.client.config` and check that connection points to development DB